# Showing multiple 'GMSMarker' markers on Google maps

Tags: swift, google-maps

I am trying to show multiple location using Google maps, the code showing only one location. I am using for loop. I checked the code using MKMapView and it's working.

Here is the code:

```
let dict = [self.jsonElement]

            for dicts in dict {

                let latiCon = (dicts.value(forKey: "lati") as! NSString).doubleValue
                let longiCon = (dicts.value(forKey: "longi") as! NSString).doubleValue

            // Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the
            // coordinate -33.86,151.20 at zoom level 6.
            let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: latiCon, longitude: longiCon, zoom: 6.0)
            let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
            self.view = mapView

            // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
            let marker = GMSMarker()
            marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latiCon, longitude: longiCon)
            marker.title = "Sydney"
            marker.snippet = "Australia"
            marker.map = mapView

            }
```

I need to show multiple locations as I said, I have a look to relative answers but I did not find anything match with my question.

Answer (score 0):

this code

```
 let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: latiCon, longitude: longiCon, zoom: 6.0)
        let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
        self.view = mapView
```

makeing a new mapView every time in loop so it's natural what you get.
a new mapview + one marker .
move this code outside loop or delete it if you already have a mapview declared before.

Comment: Hendi Ahmed you mean to remove this code and place it out of the loop Or u mean to duplicate the code

Comment: I did, now it does not show any markers, the map is loading but without any locations